# Зацикленное обновление LocalStorage (JS / Vue.js)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, localstorage

Появилась необходимость в динамическом обновлении информации у пользователя которая содержится в LocalStorage Vue.js.

LocalStorage необходимо обновлять данные скажем каждые 5 - 7 секунд. Поытался реализовать этот через цикл, но по какой то причине во Vue и axios не срабатывает цикл с тайм-аутом, то есть скрипт не ждет, а сразу же отправляет сотни запросов.

Какие вообще существуют способы обновления localStorage? Отправлять каждые n секунд запрос на сервер и проверять, есть ли новые данные? Или есть что то по лучше

Comment: async/await и sleep

Comment: не понятно зачем цикл, где именно меняются данные на сервере или клиенте? если на сервере и часто то можно попробовать работать через сокеты при получении новой порции данных записывать, если на клиенте то при изменении клиентом, для цикла не вижу смысла - он создаст лишнюю нагрузку тем более что в локал сторадж нужна сериализация сложных данных.

Comment: @DaniilLoban на клиенте, на сервере не установлена `nodejs` среда.

Comment: @Zerxa тогда каждое изменение на клиенте нужно пропускать через мидлвар который и будет заниматься сохранением, но я не знаю как у вас хранятся данные и как вы их меняете, если данные не меняются какое-то время нет смысла гонять цикл для их записи, проще всего иметь state manager который и будет синхронизироваться с localStorage